# Android - aligning view in RelativeLayout to a View in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

My root layout is a `RelativeLayout`, that contains some TextViews, Buttons and ImageViews. In the bottom part of the screen I have a `TableLayout` that represents a 4x4 grid of TextViews. I'd like to show a View (for example TextView) **aligned to bottom right** of each TextView in a grid.

so I have a

```
 <TableLayout ...>
   <TableRow ...>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/x0y0".../>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/x0y1".../>
   ....
 </TableLayout>
 ...
 <TextView  android:layout_alignTop="@id/x0y0"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/x0y0" ... />
 <TextView  android:layout_alignTop="@id/x1y1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/x1y1" ... />
```

but it's located at the **top left corner** of the screen. I suspect that Views in a RelativeLayout can only be aligned to another views inside the same RelativeLayout, but I'd like this confirmed, or better, a suggestion on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, relativelayout only can align its child nodes.  You'll need each cell in your table to contain a relative layout, pseudo-code:

```
<TableRow ...>
 <RelativeLayout ...>
  <TextView id=id/x0y0 alignParentTop="true" alignParentLeft="true" ...>
  <View alignParentRight="true" layout_below=id/x0y0 ...>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

You could also do this with vertical LinearLayout and gravity to right align the new View.